# Connecting a .NET project in Visual Studio for Mac to a SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I'm having a really hard time connecting Visual Studio for Mac to an SQL Server. I'm running SQL Server with Docker, and have a database set up and working in Azure Data Studio. Everything seems to be working there, I'm able to successfully run queries. I cannot figure out how to connect the database to a project in Visual Studio. I'm working on this project with a team, each of us is hosting the database locally. I simply need to connect the project on my end to my own local server. Apparently, there is no server explorer in Visual Studio for Mac, and I do not know how to find the connection string for my server. Any tips?

Comment: Please post the "pieces" of the connection string that you are using for Azure Data Studio.

Comment: In order to connect in Azure Data Studio, I only need server "locahost", user name "sa" and my sql password.

Comment: If you can connect with ADS using localhost and sa, you can connect similarly with this SqlClient connection string: `Data Source=localhost,User Id=sa;Password=<your-sa-password>`. You can also add `Initial Catalog=YourDatabase` for that db context instead of master.

Answer (score 0):

So I just checked my dot-net-core app running on a ubuntu linux machine (aka, no windows).  It should be the same for that mac version of linux.

My docker command:

```
sudo docker run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=peanutbutter' \
   -p 1455:1433 --name sql1Name \
   -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest
```

and the appsettings.json

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MyConnectionString": "Data Source=localhost,1455;Database=master;User Id=sa;Password=peanutbutter;"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

The above works correctly for me.

Probably not super-connected, but I have it working with both MonoDevelop and VSCode.  (Where you have VS for Mac).

FYI, and IMHO:

I purposely redirect port 1433 to 1455 to avoid ambiguity when figuring out things.  I suggest it for your own sanity in the "is this my local machine or is this a docker image" confusion.  It subtly forces your other developers to think about the port that is the default for the container vs the docker exposed one.